# PayPal Pro: is credit card validation really necessary?

Tags: paypal, credit-card, luhn

Since PayPal charges transactions but not payment authorizations, I was wondering what is the point of doing credit card validation with Luhn algorithm?

I happen to have trouble with CC validation. If it turns out not to be very important, I could simply get rid of it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question complete, but PayPal does the validation check to validate the data that is attempted to be passed before it passes it to the processor.